# Saving delivery reports against programmatically sent sms in Android phone default SMS application

Tags: android, sms, android-pendingintent

I have written an application to send SMS programmatically using SmsManager. I am passing PendingIntent for both sent sms and delivered sms notifications.

When the sent PendingIntent is received, I save that SMS in the default SMS application's Sent folder.

Later, when the delivered PendingIntent is received, I want to mark that Sent SMS entry with the delivery report, so that when the user presses and holds the sent SMS, he can see the menu option "View Report".

My question is how can I programmatically modify the Sent SMS entry in the default SMS application, and associate the Delivery Report with it? If this is not possible, how can I programmatically modify the Sent SMS entry and write the Delivery Status in the SMS message itself?

Comment: I was able to modify the sent sms entry in "content://sms/sent". I used a UUID while saving the SMS in sent folder. Later, I used that UUID to lookup the sent sms, and modify it to insert the word "DELIVERED". However, if I can find a solution to attach the Delivery Report itself, which the user can see by long press on the Sent Sms and choosing the menu option "View Report", that will be ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a UUID while saving the SMS in sent folder. Later, I used that UUID to lookup the sent sms, and modify it to insert the word "DELIVERED". Although this does not attach the Delivery Report itself to the sent sms, but it serves the purpose of informing the user whether the SMS was delivered or not. Any solutions to attach the delivery report itself, are welcome.